# Blender lag, freeze but i have a good config

Tags: rendering, system

I'm a Blender beginner, and i have a lot of lags and freezing, even sometimes completely frozen, temporarily (which is rare).

My computer specs

- GeForce GTX 1050
- Ryzen 7 3750H Radeon Vega, 4-cores 8 processors

I know there is way better but my config is already enough for Blender isn't it ?

I can run HD games (Trine 4, Minecraft, Ori etc.), HD videos and UHD videos (compressed but heavy anyway) without any problems but when i use Blender, it's lagging and freezing all the time.

For example, i'm in edit mode and go back to object mode, the transition can freeze the software.

Even once, I was doing the same thing with multiple objects in my file and it froze all my computer for a few minutes (no control, even the sound was gone).

"Undo" sequences with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> can freeze the software.

I tried some others features like image rendering and it can generate the same kind of issue.

Maybe it's a matter of optimization, i don't know i made researches but i am stuck.

Currently, my work looks like this :

[image]

And it is enough to make Blender and Windows freezing, like it was way too heavy for it. Just when i load the file and when i am working on an object in edit mode and go back to object mode.

Comment: Why I find rare is that in this kind of questions users forget to describe the kind of scene they are dealing with, making it hard to help. Games and video are heavily optimized for performance so don't take those as a measure to compare the processing that happens in blender. In order to help you please edit your question and describe the scene better: the number of vertices, the levels of subdivision, simulations, particles, armatures, scuplting, size of the textures used, number of samples, etc.

Comment: As i did say, i am a beginner so i started with simple works, in a tutorial to build a guitar. So i am modelling objects, using some modifiers like subdivision surface or mirror.

And As i did say, i encounter lag and freezing when i switch to edit mode to object mode, or when i am in edit mode with subdivision activated in it, so whatever in which situation, which scene or how many vertices, basically, with just a few objects and modifiers i have lags and freezing.

And As i did say, i can see that also when i run image rendering, just for test, whatever the file contains

Comment: Add three Level 6 Subdivision modifiers to the default cube and Blender will crash/stall on almost any machine, because Blender was not built that way. Thats just a "simple scene with a couple of modifiers".

Comment: @Leander that make sense. I've seen i had (if you look it my screenshot) the body of the guitar at level 6 subdivision and some other objects at level 5 even little detailed solids at level 4 or 5. i put everything at 3 and it works perfectly well. Thank you for your comment !